# Unable to geneate csv file from by executing .sql through shell

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I am trying to generate a csv by calling a .sql file. The issue is on execution an empty file is being created. Running the sql against the DB returns records. Apologies if this has already been answered but I was not able to find any answer that fixed my issue.

```
FILE="CASE.csv"
export dest_loc=/dest/loc
export LOGFILE=$LOG/100.$NOW_TS.log
echo "$0 started at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")" > ${LOGFILE}
sqlplus -s $DB_LOGIN<<EOSQL>>${LOGFILE}
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF    
SET sqlprompt ''    
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET trimspool ON
SET trimout ON
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP "|"
SET LINESIZE 650
SPOOL $dest_loc/$FILE
@$SRC/sql_to_run.sql
SPOOL OFF
EOSQL
echo "\nChecking for ORACLE errors..."                            >> ${LOGFILE}
grep 'ORA-' $LOGFILE                                              >> ${LOGFILE}
rc=$?
if [ ${rc} = 0 ];
then
   echo "\nThere has been an ORACLE error. RC = $RC"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "\n$0 ended at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "####################################"  >> ${LOGFILE}
   exit 2
else 
   echo "\nNo ORACLE errors found."   >> ${LOGFILE}
fi
```

The log file captured

> ./100.sh started at 2021-10-20:20:14:22 Checking for ORACLE errors...
> No ORACLE errors found.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `csv` file is empty is probably because you have an error that you are not capturing. `sqlplus` is a binary program, so it will exit always with 0, unless you use `whenever sqlerror` and `whenever oserror` in order to capture exceptions produced in the execution, either because of a database error or a operating system issue.

**Prior to 12c**

```
FILE="CASE.csv"
export dest_loc=/dest/loc
export LOGFILE=$LOG/100.$NOW_TS.log
echo "$0 started at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")" > ${LOGFILE}
sqlplus -s $DB_LOGIN << EOSQL >> ${LOGFILE}
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE;
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF    
SET sqlprompt ''    
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET trimspool ON
SET trimout ON
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP "|"
SET LINESIZE 650
SPOOL $dest_loc/$FILE
@$SRC/sql_to_run.sql
SPOOL OFF
EOSQL
rc=$?
if [ ${rc} -ne 0 ];
then
   echo "\nThere has been an ORACLE error. RC = $RC"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "\n$0 ended at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "####################################"  >> ${LOGFILE}
   exit 2
else 
   echo "\nNo ORACLE errors found."   >> ${LOGFILE}
fi
```

**12c or higher**

If you are in this version, you might want to use the feature `set markup csv` to generate files.

```
FILE="CASE.csv"
export dest_loc=/dest/loc
export LOGFILE=$LOG/100.$NOW_TS.log
echo "$0 started at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")" > ${LOGFILE}
sqlplus -s $DB_LOGIN << EOSQL >> ${LOGFILE}
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE;
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF    
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET LINESIZE 650
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET MARKUP CSV ON DELIMITER "|"
SPOOL $dest_loc/$FILE
@$SRC/sql_to_run.sql
SPOOL OFF
EOSQL
rc=$?
if [ ${rc} -ne 0 ];
then
   echo "\nThere has been an ORACLE error. RC = $RC"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "\n$0 ended at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   echo "##########################################"   >> ${LOGFILE}
   exit 2;
else 
   echo "\nNo ORACLE errors found."   >> ${LOGFILE}
fi
```

**Test Sqlplus Exit Status**

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 21 08:32:27 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> create table t1 ( c1 number );
create table t1 ( c1 number )
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
[ftpcpl@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ echo $?
0
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 21 08:32:43 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> whenever sqlerror exit failure;
SQL> create table t1 ( c1 number );
create table t1 ( c1 number )
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
$ echo $?
1
```